# How to cURL POST a filename with spaces?

Tags: curl, post

I'm doing a cURL POST request to an API.

One of the form fields is a file, and the desired file name might contain spaces...

If I send the following as the curl option then the file arrives at the other end named simply "HID"

```
-F attachment=@file1.ext;filename=HID Global member list 12 October 2020.pdf;type=application/pdf
```

I've tried URL-encoding the filename, and wrapping the filename with quotes. The former gets passed thru without any decoding, and the latter results in a filename of `'HID`

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotes for the entire form, not only for the filename.

Linux/Mac example

```
 curl -F "attachment=@file1.ext;filename=HID Global member list 12 October 2020.pdf;type=application/pdf" localhost/send-form-url
```